# How to travel without transit visa from India to Stockholm?

Tags: visas, transit, indian-citizens, sweden

I need to travel from Coimbatore (India) to Stockholm Arlanda (Sweden). I have a Swedish residence permit.

Could you help me find a route across the world for which I would not need any transit visa?

Comment: Is your residence permit for some reason only valid for Sweden, or are you allowed to travel freely withing the Schengen area?

Comment: My residence permit is for Master Studies at Sweden

Answer (score 7):

This will not answer your question directly, but the following will tell you that you can go through any [Schengen country](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Area) on your way. That should open up a long list of possible travel routes from India to Sweden.

A PUT (Permanent uppehållstillstånd, [Permanent Residence Permit](http://www.migrationsverket.se/info/3135_en.html)) for Sweden (or any other Schengen country) works the same as a Schengen Visa. That means you can travel through any Schengen country on your way to/from Sweden, even take a vacation in say Norway.

> Foreign citizens with residence permits in a Schengen country, and whose identities have been properly established, may also travel freely in the zone for three months.

From the [Swedish migration office](http://www.migrationsverket.se/info/219_en.html) website.

Comment: BTW, although you officially can only travel for three months in the rest of the Schengen area there is not much that is keeping you from going about the rest of Europe pretty much unrestricted, as there are no border controls between the Schengen countries.

Comment: @Tamilselvan After reading the question again I notice you do not have a PUT, but the same applies to any kind of Residence Permit. Good travels!

Answer (score 4):

For example, [Rome To Rio](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Coimbatore/Stockholm) gives some possible routes.

It suggests, for example, to go through Doha or Dubai. As far as I know, as long as you do not leave the international transit area, you do not need a transit visa for [Doha](http://support.qatarairways.com/entries/20456948-Do-I-need-a-visa-for-transiting-in-Doha-) or [Dubai](http://www.dubaifaqs.com/visa-transit-dubai.php).